# Appending MySQL Results Together in a PHP Loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Using PHP, for-each row in a MySQL query's result set, I need to execute another MySQL query. So far, I've got

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id, state FROM states WHERE region='given_region'")
or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $state = $row['state'];
    $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM locations WHERE state REGEXP '(^|,)".$state."($|,)'");
}
```

Now I need to append all of the results $r into ONE result set that I can then iterate through with a standard while-loop, however, my very limited PHP skills are leaving me at a loss getting code to do that.

Can anyone provide any insight into how I'd go about appending all the results into one set within the given while loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Learn about [SQL joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html):

```sql
SELECT states.id, states.state, locations.*
FROM   states LEFT JOIN locations USING(state)
WHERE  states.region = 'given_region'
```

Comment: I do struggle with more advanced Joins, so I might be wrong, but I don't think I can use a Join in my case. I oversimplified my example too much above. In the query in the while loop, I'm actually matching a single value, state, to a possible value within a comma separated list. So the 'state' column is actually a list of states and I want to match for all rows where $state is in that list. I've modified my example above.

Comment: @JToland: I'd strongly suggest that you [normalise](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your schema.  But if that's not possible, you could replace `USING(state)` above with `ON FIND_IN_SET(states.state,locations.state)`

Comment: I know normalising the data would certainly be the best way to go about this long term, but unfortunately that's not something I can easily change (or at least not quickly enough to suit my current need). I tried the above query with the `ON FIND_IN_SET` and that's working beautifully! It seems to give me exactly what I need and is much easier than how I was trying to do it before, thanks a lot @eggyal!

Answer (score 0):

You could try and use foreach instead of while. I'm sorry but i'm not really getting the question.

If you  use a foreach you can generate entire tables with it if you'd like to. let me give you an example:

```
<?php
Foreach($result as $output) : ?>
<div id="results">
<table id="generated table">
<tr>
<td><?php echo $output->id ?></td><td> <?php echo $output->state ?></td>
</tr>
</table>
<?php endforeach ?>
 </div>
```

Mind you, if you use foreaches you can just get the ENTIRE table instead of using the query to select a few columns. Then you output the columns data through the foreach (by using the $output->columnname command)